# SNOWFLAKE Cumulative window frame unsupported for function SUM

Tags: sql, sum, max, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I am working with an SNOWFLAKE [snowflake](/questions/tagged/snowflake)  database.
And I am trying some windows operators using the snowflake `SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA` database, and I encounter a situation with the cumulative functions.

The SQL that is not working is the following:

```sql
SELECT 
SUM( C_BIRTH_DAY )
OVER (PARTITION BY
     C_BIRTH_MONTH,
     C_BIRTH_YEAR 
     ORDER BY
     NVL(C_BIRTH_COUNTRY,'COSTA RICA')
     RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS MAX1,
MIN( C_BIRTH_DAY )
OVER ( PARTITION BY C_BIRTH_MONTH ,
     C_BIRTH_YEAR 
     ORDER BY
     NVL(C_BIRTH_COUNTRY,'COSTA RICA')
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS MIN1
FROM  CUSTOMER;
```

The provided SQL will fail returning an error message:
`SNOWFLAKE Cumulative window frame unsupported for function SUM`.

And the expected result is that the query should be executed.

I tried this query with several operators `AVG`,`MAX`,`SUM` and with all I got the same results.

Looking at the [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-analytic.html#label-window-frames) it looks like the syntax is fine:

For cumulative windows

```
cumulativeFrame ::=
    {
       { ROWS | RANGE } BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW
     | { ROWS | RANGE } BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    }
```

And for sliding windows:

```
slidingFrame ::=
    {
       ROWS BETWEEN <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING } AND <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING }
     | ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING }
     | ROWS BETWEEN <N> { PRECEDING | FOLLOWING } AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
    }
```

So I currently cannot find an explanation for this error.

Answer (score 2):

After trying all sort of things I found that if I switch the window syntax and instead of using RANGE I use rows like this:

```sql
SELECT 
SUM( C_BIRTH_DAY )
OVER (PARTITION BY
     C_BIRTH_MONTH,
     C_BIRTH_YEAR 
     ORDER BY
     NVL(C_BIRTH_COUNTRY,'CR')
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS MAX1,
MIN( C_BIRTH_DAY )
OVER ( PARTITION BY C_BIRTH_MONTH ,
     C_BIRTH_YEAR 
     ORDER BY
     NVL(C_BIRTH_COUNTRY,'CR')
     ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS MIN1
FROM  CUSTOMER;
```

It works!!